# How do I check the state of this CheckButton?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to pull the states from both Checkbuttons to use in an if statement, how do I do that?

```
CheckVar1 = tkinter.IntVar()
CheckVar2 = tkinter.IntVar()
C1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text="Yes", variable=CheckVar1)
C1.grid(row=7, column=1)
C2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text="No", variable=CheckVar2)
C2.grid(row=8, column=1)
```

Comment: ***"how do I do that?"***: You are using the search function of SO instead of asking: [`[python][tkinter] Checkbutton state`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+Checkbutton+state)

Comment: @stovfl thanks for your help, I had to use BooleanVar() instead of IntVar()